# How do I create a new GCE VM instance from an instance template using GCE Node.js client?

Tags: google-compute-engine, google-api-nodejs-client

In [Google compute engine](https://cloud.google.com/compute/) I can use an [instance template](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-templates/) to create a new VM from the template. This works fine using the GCE-console, and works fine, using the [API](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/instances/insert), too (URL parameter "sourceInstanceTemplate").

How can I create a new GCE-VM from an instance template using [googleapis/nodejs-compute](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-compute) (the Node.js GCE SDK)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[google-auth-library-nodejs](https://github.com/google/google-auth-library-nodejs) can be used for accessing the [GCE instances.insert API](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/instances/insert) directly.

The following example is adapted from https://github.com/google/google-auth-library-nodejs and works fine, if executed within GCE (in special, in a [Google Cloud Function](https://cloud.google.com/functions/)).

```
const zone = 'some-zone';
const name = 'a-name';
const sourceInstanceTemplate = `some-template-name`;
createVM(zone, name, sourceInstanceTemplate)
  .then(console.log)
  .catch(console.error);

async function createVM(zone, vmName, templateName) {
  const {auth} = require('google-auth-library');
  const client = await auth.getClient({
    scopes: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform'
  });
  const projectId = await auth.getDefaultProjectId();

  const sourceInstanceTemplate = `projects/${projectId}/global/instanceTemplates/${templateName}`;
  const url = `https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/${projectId}/zones/${zone}/instances?sourceInstanceTemplate=${sourceInstanceTemplate}`;

  return await client.request({
    url: url,
    method: 'post',
    data: {name: vmName}
  });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I can't find the solution in the documentation for the node client. Hopefully my ***alternate*** solution helps someone.

```
const exec = require('child-process-promise').exec;

var create_vm = (zone, vmname, templatename) => {
  const cmd =  `gcloud compute instances create ${vmname} ` +
      `--zone=${zone} ` +
      `--source-instance-template=${templatename} `;
  return exec(cmd);
};

create_vm('us-central1-c', 'my-instance', 'whatever')
    .then(console.log)
    .catch(console.error);
```

You can customize this as far as gcloud lets you. The docs/options for creating an instance are [here](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/instances/create).

Comment: Excellent workaround, thanks for the inspiration!
Unfortunately, I cannot use it. I am within a https://cloud.google.com/functions/ , where gcloud-tool is not available (I tested it 'stderr: '/bin/sh: 1: gcloud: not found\n' }' ).